# Change combobox list to clear option

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got combobox which is non editable with dropdownlist style. By deafult is blank when I open a form. When user choose an option of list and click button I want to set it back to non option position. How I can do that ?

Comment: please post your code. What you have tried so far etc. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line in your button click event. This will change the selected index of your combobox to -1 which will display nothing (blank).

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```